# creating imageview dinamicly in recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: ViewHolder,
    position: Int
    ){ 
       // some code there
   var image= ImageView(holder.itemView.context)
        image.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 60)
        image.maxHeight = 20
        image.maxWidth = 20
        IMustTakeSomethingThere???????.addView(image)
      }
```

So I’m trying to add imageView dynamically, since there can be several pictures and it is not known in advance how many. I can’t figure out where to add the view, as this is done in the Recycleview in the Fragment. What I have to write instead the IMustTakeSomethingThere???????

Answer (score 1):

You need a parent view for your ImageView. In your item layout xml file, give id to the parent element, if it is a layout. for example, LinearLayout.

Now you can access this parent element to add ImageView in it. Use

```
holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_id).addView(image)
```

holder.itemView is the view for each RecyclerView item.

Comment: I tried. There is no addView() function in holder.itemView   ((

Comment: @Killbit If this answer solves your problem, accept it as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

You can add any `Layout` to your `ViewHolder` class. For example `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. Then you are able to do: `viewHolder.linearLayout.addView()`

Answer (score 0):

```
val layout = holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.linear_layout)
layout.addView(image)
```